# How to fix protractor e2e test issue: E/launcher - invalid session id?

Tags: angular, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am able to run protractor e2e test successfully,

```
'Executed 8 of 8 specs SUCCESS in 2 mins 57 secs.'
```

but at the end of test it is giving me below three warnings/issues, so i expect here it should be clear console without any warning/error/issue. Below are the details of warnings,

1. `E/launcher - invalid session id`
2. `E/launcher - NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id`
3. `E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199`

Solutions tried to fix this warnings, already have mentioned config settings for `useAllAngular2AppRoots: true` and `directConnect: true` in `'protractor.config.js'`.

Could someone please help me, how to clear these warnings from console/output of test result?

Answer (score -1):

Try closing the session and browser window on the end of the test and check the behavior of the logs.